# What is a regular expression I can use in Vim to find CVS conflicts?

Tags: regex, version-control, vim, cvs

What is a regular expression I can use in Vim to find conflicts in CVS and possibly other version control systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here is a regular expression to find entire conflict sections:**

```
[<]\{7}.*\_.\{-}[=]\{7}\_.\{-}[>]\{7}.*
```

And to search for that in vim, just press the '/' key and paste that regular-expression string, then press enter.

**Usually CVS conflicts look like this:**

```
<<<<<<< file.c
Code from file.c
=======
Code from the repository version 1.2
>>>>>>> 1.2
```

**Vim search-and-replace command to keep *local* version:**

```
:%s/[<]\{7}.*\n\(\_.\{-}\)[=]\{7}\_.\{-}[>]\{7}.*\n/\1/g
```

**Vim search-and-replace command to keep *repository* version:**

```
:%s/[<]\{7}.*\_.\{-}[=]\{7}\n\(\_.\{-}\)[>]\{7}.*\n/\1/g
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually just do `/<<<` and press 'n' until I find no more matches. It is a much less sophisticated approach than Neil's, but it works for me :)